# Accessing SQL database on remote server

Tags: c#, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Just recently I've created a new website for me and my team, so I can create a login-system to use with my programs, mainly because most of them are exclusive to specific sites.
Now, the main program is written in Java, but the launcher is written in C# as it has to handle prerequisites, such as searching for updates and installing separate files.

And it's this launcher where the user first logs in before anything else happens.

I have a phpMyAdmin thinga-madoohickey, but I've never worked with this sort of thing. (I only bought the domain, everything else was done by other people)
How can I connect to the database and efficiently query for the usernames and password? I'd have to hash them first, but that's a different story.

I've searched on quite a few threads but I've seen barely any similarities with my question, same goes with threads on MSDN, either they were closed, or ignored.

Any help on this topic would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are really looking for is how to connect to MySQL from Java. While doing so, you won't be going via phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin is a web interface for MySQL, this is where you can prepare your database. Then, your Java application will be the one used by your team.

Comment: No, I'mm most definitely looking to connect to mySQL from C#, as the launcher is written in C# and what good is it if the user downloads and installs the files before using the actual program, just to find out he has to back out anyway because he doesn't have an account, and then he'd have to completely uninstall everything in the case that he doesn't want to create an account.

Comment: I think Marc's point is that even if you use your C# launcher for authentication, the Java application is what's going to be accessing MySQL for the purposes of manipulating the data in your database...otherwise you're just using the database for authentication for your launcher, and there are better ways of doing that (PAM, Kerberos, NSS, Active Directory, etc). Based on what you're saying, it sounds like your intention is to connect to MySQL from the C# launcher and Java application, so you'll probably want to start your Google search there.